# Revert failed cloud foundry deploy

Tags: database-migration, cloud-foundry, rollback

I'm automating app deployment to cloud foundry. So in the start command, I do a db migration. What can happen is that the migration would fail and as the result, the app will be dead. Is there some predefined strategy that can be used to rollback to the last working deployment, or I should manually store the last working version, check for failure and in that case redeploy the stored version?

Answer (score 3):

The typical strategy used to deploy apps on Cloud Foundry is blue/green.  This generally works like this:

1. Push the new app under a new name & host, like `my-app-new`.
2. Test the app & make sure it works.
3. When your satisfied, change the route mapping from the old app to the new app.
4. Delete the old app & optionally rename the new app.

Step #3 is where the cut-over happens.  Prior to that all traffic keeps flowing to the old app.

This is documented more here.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html

I'd say this often works well, but sometimes there are problems.  Where this breaks down is with steps #1 & #2, if your app cannot have multiple instances of itself running or if migrations to your service are so different that the old app breaks when you update the database.  It definitely helps if you keep this strategy in mind as you develop your app.

Aside from that, which has historically been the way to go, you could take a look at the [new v3 API](http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.36.0/index.html#introduction) functionality.  With v3, apps now retain multiple versions of a droplet.  With this, you can rollback to a previous version of a droplet.

http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.36.0/index.html#droplets

You can run `cf v3-droplets` to see the available droplets and `cf v3-set-droplet` to change the droplet being used.

That said, this will only rollback the droplet.  It would not rollback a service like a database schema.  If you need to do that, you'd need reverse migrations or perhaps even restore from a backup.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I work on very similar automation processes.

Daniel has explained the process very well. I think you're looking for the blue-green deployment methodology

1) Read up on blue green deploy here:
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html

2) Look at this plugin or implement blue green deploy manually:
https://github.com/contraband/autopilot

3) Blue-green restage plugin (a nice to have, in case you need to restage the app but not cause any downtime to the clients):
https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/cf-plugin-bg-restage

It works by creating a temporary app, copying the env vars/routes/code from the working app to he temp app.
The temp app now accepts traffic while the original app is being restaged.
the traffic moves on to the original app after it is restaged and the temporary app is deleted.